# How to clear the input of Vuetify's v-autocomplete from element in it's #clear slot?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

So I have a `<v-autocomplete>` that I want to be clearable. If I just set the `clearable` attribute it works BUT I have a custom icon component that I want to display instead of the default clear icon. According to the docs I can use the `#clear` slot for that. So I used that and placed my icon component in there but clicking on it doesn't clear the input field anymore.

*I tried clearing the model with `@click` on the icon element but it didn't work either.*

Here is my code: (I replaced the custom icon component with `<button>` for the example)

```js
<template>
<v-autocomplete
    ref="searchInput"
    v-model="inputVal"
    clearable
    label="Placeholder"
    :items="items"
    variant="outlined"
    :class="$style['text-input']">
    <template #clear>
        <button type="button" @click="clearInput">X</button>
    </template>
</v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
type SearchItem = {
    value: number | string
    title: string
}

export type Props = {
    searchFieldPlaceholderText: string
}
</script>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue"

const inputVal = ref<number | string | undefined>()
const searchInput = ref<any>()

const items: Array<SearchItem> = [
    {
        title: "Item 1",
        value: 1,
    },
    {
        title: "Item 2",
        value: 2,
    },
]
const clearInput = () => {
    inputVal.value = null
    console.log(searchInput)
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" module>
.text-input {
    max-width: 400px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think this is a bug. When using the slot, the `onClear` handler is not triggered and no `click:clear` event will fire.

The `#clear` slot probably should pass an onClear callback, but it doesn't. Only workaround for now is to implement the clear yourself:

```
<template #clear>
  <button @click="inputVal = null">X</button>
</template>
```

---

Using the [`:clear-icon`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-autocomplete/#props-clear-icon) prop does not have this limitation. You could pass in your component there:

```html
<script setup>
  import { h } from 'vue'
  import YourCustomIconComponent from '...'

  const ClearIconComponent = () => h(YourCustomIconComponent, {icon: 'mdi-close'})
</script>
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    :clear-icon="ClearIconComponent"
    ...
  />
</template>
```

see [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following <template #clear> within the < v-autocomplete > component:

```
 <template #clear>
<v-icon @click = " vmodelOfSelector = '' " >mdi-close</v-icon>
</template>
```

**vmodelOfSelector** is the value (v-model) bound  to < v-autocomplete > component. When you click the icon, vmodelOfSelector sets the value equal to a blank space ''."